# How to Create keyspace in cassandra1.1.9

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am trying to create keyspace in cassandra1.1.9 and I did the same way how 'help create keyspace' tell me.

> CREATE KEYSPACE testkeyspace
>   with placement_strategy = 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy'
>   and strategy_options = [{replication_factor:2}];
>   
>    EVEN TRIED THIS
>   create keyspace testkeyspace;
>   update keyspace testkeyspace with placement_strategy = 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy'
>   and strategy_options = {replication_factor:3};
>
> ---
>
> I always got this error:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient$AddKeyspaceArgument.STRATEGY_OPT:ONS

Comment: If you plan to use quorum, you probably do not want a replication factor of 2. A quorum read or write is rf /2 + 1 - so quorum is the same as all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using cassandra-cli this is the correct syntax:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE testkeyspace
with placement_strategy = 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy'
and strategy_options = {replication_factor:2};
```

Comment: doees not change anything.

Answer (score 7):

I'm on version 1.2.8 but the only syntax that worked for me is this:

```
create keyspace demo with replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':1}
```

Comment: Add the semicolon in the end as well

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

"CREATE KEYSPACE #{keyspace} WITH strategy_class = 'SimpleStrategy' AND strategy_options:replication_factor = 3"

Answer (score 0):

```
cqlsh:CREATE KEYSPACE keyspace_name 
      WITH strategy_class='SimpleStrategy' AND strategy_options:replication_factor='1';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having multiple datacenters in cassandra cluster and want to store one copy in each data center then u can use below command:

Below command is for CLI interface:

```
create keyspace KEY_SPACE  with placement_strategy = 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy' and strategy_options={DC1:1, DC2:1, DC3:1};
```